# ASP.NET MVC with User Defined Type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, clr, entity-framework-6

I try to create simple ASP.NET MVC5 app where I can access to my table. The table has user defined type inside.

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs

Unfortunately, when I use Entity Data Model and try to generate model from database, my UDT field is ignored. I've got an warning:

> The data type 'Pesel' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'x' in the table 'y' was excluded.

So my question is, how can I add my UDT to entity model?

I've tried to manually create a model and then use Entity Framework to generate controller and views. Again, UDT fields are ignored.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I've personally not used User Defined Types, but I'm sure you have a good reason for it.  After reading your question, I decided to learn more about UDT's and try and find an answer for you.  From what I've read, you should be able to do it as long as you reference the assembly for the definition in your project. Otherwise, your project will have no idea what the data type is or how to use it.

Here is some text from the "Professional C# 4 and .Net 4" book:

> Using UDTs from Client - side Code
>
> The assembly of the UDT must be referenced to use the UDT from client
>   - side code. Then it can be used like any other type on the client.
>
> Because the assembly containing the UDTs is used both from the client
>   and from the SQL Server, it is a good idea to put UDTs in a separate
>   assembly from the other SQL Server extensions such as stored
>   procedures and functions.

Comment: I've add reference to the assembly with my UDT, and my web project recognise that types. The problem is, I cannot generate controler to the entity model with UDT. This fields are being ingored.